# Exception error in java when moving from ubuntu 12.04 to 10.04

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

I am making a data acquisition software using  [Sparrow's Kmax](http://www.sparrowcorp.com/products/software). I am writing the code on my ubuntu 12.04 laptop. One of the methods I have created is the following

```
public double getValueFrom(String widgName) {//Read data from user input text fields
    KmaxWidget widg = tlsh.getKmaxWidget(widgName); 
    String str = widg.getProperty("TEXT");

    double num = 0;
    try {
        num = Double.parseDouble(str);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        tlsh.setProperty("STATUSSTR", "Attention! Channel and Energy must be double precision number. i.e. 10, 3.14 etc.");
        tlsh.showWarning("Choose a double precision number.");
        throw e;
    }
    return num; 
} // getValueFrom
```

When I compile the code on my laptop it goes without any error. When I copy my code to the ubuntu 10.04 desktop I get an exception code

```
unreported exception java.lang Exception: must be caught or declared to be thrown
throw e;
^
```

The first thing that crossed my mind was that they have different versions of java. Indeed that was true, so I updated 10.04's java, but again the same error occurs. Any idea on what might be wrong?

**EDIT** I also added `throws Exception` after method's arguments but whenever this method is called I get the error(on both systems)

```
unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Comment: That code isn't valid in *any* version of Java. I'm deeply suspicious of your claim that it compiles on your laptop. You simply *can't* throw a `java.lang.Exception` from a method that doesn't declare it.

Comment: You can't compile this in Any Java version.

Comment: @JonSkeet: How can I prove that the aforementioned code compiles on my laptop? In the box bellow "channel" I entered "p" in order to make the warning box pop-out. http://imgur.com/vDMUQfG

Comment: @Thanos actually JonSkeet is right.

Comment: @Thanos: It would help if you would provide a short but *complete* program which you can compile, which contains `throw new java.lang.Exception();` (without catching it) in a method which doesn't declare that it throws `Throwable` or `Exception`. I suspect you'll have a hard time writing such a program.

Comment: I am not sure if I provide with a code that can work, without having Kmax. However the shortest code I can provide that is working can be found here http://pastebin.com/xw3fzqBq

Comment: @Thanos: Why would you need to use kmax to provide code that doesn't need to actually *accomplish* anything, it just needs to compile?

Comment: @Thanos please accept one of the answers.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Because the methods are linked to objects created in a canvas that is provided from Kmax.

Comment: @Thanos: They are in the code you happen to have at the moment. That doesn't mean they have to be for a program just trying to reproduce the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is coming because of :

```
 throw e;
```

Since you are throwing a java.lang.Exception object from your catch block your method signature has to include throws clause stating this and therefore your method signature now becomes (or else your compiler will complain):

```
  public double getValueFrom(String widgName) throws Exception
```

This change will resolve the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! When I add `throws Exception` I get the error `unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown` whenever my method is called...

Comment: Thats how it should be since this is a checked exception. You will have to either catch or re-throw the exception where-ever getValueFrom is being called.

Comment: This is  a basic java concept Thanos. What you need to do is that wherever you are calling this method add a throws Exception clause in that method definition and finally you can catch is at the up-most end of the call hierarchy. This is a crude approach since i do not know about your business use case but will definately help.

Comment: @Thanos: I suspect you'll find that the problem has moved to the code *calling* the method. Using bare `Exception` is a bad idea anyway, to be honest. How much understanding do you have of checked exceptions in Java?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I've never used `Exceptions` in java before, so my understanding on this matter is quite a little...

Comment: @Thanos: Right, in that case I suggest you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 2):

As the exception says this function it should through the exception to parent class, so you define your function to through exeption like below

```
public double getValueFrom(String widgName) throws Exception
{
 // body
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! When I add `throws Exception` I get the error `unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown` whenever my method is called...

Comment: you need to handle the exception in the parent class or throw it as you through the exception like above